# How can I convert +00:00 timezone to Z timezone

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, utc

I am comparing the following dates as:

result = `2018-06-29T20:56:41+00:00 <= 2018-06-30T00:38:32Z`

But this is giving as false. How can I make the 2 dates compare to True as Cleary 29 < 30. Initially, I thought it has to do with the timezone but on google search, found out that both formats are UTC timezone. Can anyone help me understand if that's correct and then compare these results to true?

Comment: Unless you're using a very exotic Python version, `"2018-06-29T20:56:41+00:00" <= "2018-06-30T00:38:32Z"` will evaluate to `True`. That's the main point of the [`ISO 8601`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Answer (score 2):

Are you actually converting them to `datatime` objects, e.g.:

```
In []:
d1 = datetime.strptime("2018-06-29T20:56:41+00:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
d2 = datetime.strptime("2018-06-30T00:38:32Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
d1 <= d2

Out[]:
True
```

Note: in Py3.7 the first of these could be replaced with [`datetime.fromisoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat)

But even the string forms should also return `True`, so not sure why you are getting `False`:

```
In []:
"2018-06-29T20:56:41+00:00" <= "2018-06-30T00:38:32Z"

Out[]:
True
```

Comment: Thanks @zwer and AChampion. I was getting different date formats in my response. I decided to use pandas to_datetime to remove the dependency on the format. It's one of those errors that I don't know why to was happening but works now. I did couple of changes and I didn't keep track of which change worked.